# Run background process without Banno Card displayed

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I didn't see anything in the documentation so I don’t think this is possible, but I want to confirm.

Is there any way to have a background process run without there being a Banno Card displayed?

I’m currently creating a way to notify the user that they aren’t enrolled in e-statements. However, I would need there to always be a Banno card (plugin) displayed so that the program uses the API and generates a popup when the user logs in.

If possible I would like to be able to "hide" the plugin so that the process is ran in the background.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to run a background process within the Banno UI as you have described.

It’s possible to run processes outside of Banno itself and still use Banno’s APIs (see answer to [Consumer API - Using Authentication Framework via a "background" service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243448/consumer-api-using-authentication-framework-via-a-background-service)), but that is different from what you are looking to do.